# Angular - Displaying an object using a dynamic variable?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
{{ currentProductDetails.metadata.spec_category_0_spec_image }}
```

But I need the **0** to reference another variable.  So something like this:

```
{{ currentProductDetails.metadata.spec_category_{{ configView }}_spec_image }}
```

but that obviously doesn't work. Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) here:

```
{{ currentProductDetails.metadata['spec_category_' + configView + '_spec_image'] }}
```

Think of `currentProductDetails.metadata` as an object, and with `'spec_category_' + configView + '_spec_image'` you construct dynamic property key of it.